# $ is not defined for anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I'm sure that my jquery script include is there and so jquery has been pulled in but I for some reason get ReferenceError: $ is not defined for $(function ().

It was working fine but then at some point it started not to recognize jquery and I don't see what could be causing that if jquery is loaded.  I don't think I need a document.ready() do I?

Honestly I don't even know if I should be using an anonymous function here.  I forget why I have it in the first place because it's just wrapping a bunch of functions inside, I'm basically wrapping all my js and jquery code within it for the page.

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var creditCardType = 1;
        var cVV2 = 123;


        //$ is a shorthand for 'jQuery'. So $(function(){}); is a jquery function
        $(function ()
        {
            hideAllTransactionSections();
            setEvents();

            function hideAllTransactionSections() {
                $("#preAuthenticationContent").hide();
                $("#delayCaptureContent").hide();
                $("#captureContent").hide();
                $("#voidContent").hide();
                $("#refundContent").hide();
            }
           ... rest of js code for the page
       });
```

Not sure why I get this error still.

Comment: check whether the path of the jquery resource is correct

Comment: also in your console check whether there are any errors...

Comment: Can you provide Fiddle please?

Comment: in your browser console check `jQuery`

Comment: Did you publish your project to IIS? You might find the path is different from your test environment.

Comment: problem is I had this comment but not sure why that would have any effect but it did somehow.     <body id="page-home" class="front logged-in no-sidebars" data-twttr-rendered="true">
        
        <!-- DON'T PUT INLINES STYLES IN HERE PERIOD, NO EXCEPTION, KEEP THIS CODE CLEAN -->

        <div id="page">

Answer (score 0):

This means that the jQuery library not being found. Check to make sure that you src path is correct.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

You could also have a syntax error further down in the file, you might need to provide the full js code.

Comment: Why the downvote - its either the path is wrong or there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have given right path .*i.e ur JS file is loaded on page*

or else do use below link

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Bu using above JS , if still you getting error check your console page your
 error msg

Answer (score 0):

Since you (more or less) asked, `$(function (){})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function (){})`. You add that so none of the jQuery code inside that wrapper executes until the DOM is ready.

As for why it's undefined, the two most common problems are

1. Path is not valid (you should see a 404 error in the console)
2. Another script has already mapped to the `$` operator

You haven't tagged this as an ASP.NET MVC question, but if it is, you have to be using MVC4 or higher to get automatic mapping of the virtual directory (from the `~` character). Otherwise, you need to use the `@Url.Content()` helper.